# can two methods have different return type in method overriding in java

Tags: java, overriding

I want to ask that in method overriding , can the method have different return type..

For eg.

```
class A{
    int x(){
       System.out.print("1");
    }
}

class B extends A{
    void x(){
       System.out.print("2");
    }
}

class C{
    public static void main(){
       A a = new B();
       a.x();
    }
}
```

What will be the o/p and whether it is called overriding.

Comment: This code does not compile. That is pretty much ALWAYS a sign that you are not doing something correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you sorta can but in a limited fashion. A child class may return a **sub-class** of the **class** returned by the parent.

```
 class A{
  Object x(){
   System.out.print("1");
   }
  }

class B extends A{
 @Override
 String x(){
   System.out.print("2");
 }
}
```

Other than this sub-class relationship b/w the return types, No.

Comment: This is true. It should be noted that the underlying method signature is the same, as all sub-classes of a particular class are of their inherited type, by definition, which is _why_ this works.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you're specifying here, as you will get a compiler error specifying that your method you're attempting to override clashes with the new definition, using an incompatible return type.

In order to override a method, you need to have the same method signature. You can use the `@Override` annotation to test this.

Answer (score 0):

**No**  different `return` `type` isn't method overriding, verify by adding `@Override` annotation